# Make the top left of a JFrame (0,0)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

I'm doing some tiling in a JFrame and I just think it would be easier to deal with if the top left of the map was (0,0), as it makes it easier to interpret positions via 2d arrays.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Well, you stated your opinion but what do you expect from us?

Comment: A component coordinate space is always 0x0 at the top/left.  `MouseListener`s attached to a component will automatically transform the `MosueEvent` to the coordinate space (so they offset from the top/left corner of the component).  The frame's decorations are painted WITHIN the boundaries of the frame, this means that 0x0 of the frame is actually under the frame title.  Instead, as has already been suggested, use a `JPanel` and apply it the frame's `contentPane`.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm doing some tiling in a JFrame

You should NOT be doing tiling in the frame.

Instead you add a `JPanel` to the frame and do the tiling in the panel. Then the top/left of the panel will be(0, 0).

Read the section from the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). There are topics on:

1. `Custom painting` - if you are painting your own tiles. The tutorial shows how to do custom painting on the panel
2. `How to use GridLayout` - if you want to add real components to the panel.

In either case the frame is just a container for the panel. All the code/logic belongs in the panel.